# Buttons not showing up when adding a Form Panel with buttons to an Ext.window.Window

Tags: javascript, extjs

Here's a description of my Fiddle

- I have defined a Window and a Form Panel
- I have created instances of the Window and the Form panel defined above
- Added the Form panel to the Window
- Called the .show() on the Window to show the window (which
  now also includes the form)

The form Panel declaration includes the buttons. But now the buttons do not show up.

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'My Window',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('MyWindow', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'My Window'//,
            // renderTo: Ext.getBody()
        });

        Ext.define('MyForm', {
            extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
            bodyPadding: 5,
            width: 350,

            // The form will submit an AJAX request to this URL when submitted
            url: '',

            // Fields will be arranged vertically, stretched to full width
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%'
            },

            // The fields
            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [{
                fieldLabel: 'First Name',
                name: 'first',
                allowBlank: false
            }, {
                fieldLabel: 'Last Name',
                name: 'last',
                allowBlank: false
            }],

            // Reset and Submit buttons
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Reset',
                handler: function () {
                    this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Submit',
                formBind: true, //only enabled once the form is valid
                disabled: true,
                handler: function () {
                    var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                    if (form.isValid()) {
                        form.submit({
                            success: function (form, action) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
                            },
                            failure: function (form, action) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        var myWindow = new MyWindow();
        var myForm = new MyForm();

        myWindow.items.add(myForm);
        myWindow.show();
        // var myForm = new MyForm();

    }
});
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1sv9)

This must be related to some documented behavior of the Form or the Window. What could that be?
Also, architecturally, I would like to define these components separately and use them as needed. So is there a design pattern that is better than this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any component that is going to contain other components will generally need to have a layout specified. Add `layout: 'fit'` to your MyWindow config and it should work.

Google ExtJS MVC for guidelines on the recommended way to design ExtJS applications. I also find that the ExtJS 6 examples page can be quite useful. The [KitchenSink](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#all) one is nice because it contains a ton of different examples of small applications built using the MVC design pattern. (Pick an example from that link and then expand the Details pane on the right.)

Comment: Is there a defined behavior on what happens when layout config is missing? It's just weird that the buttons are ignored when layout is missing. Your answer makes sense that without layout the Window config doesn't work properly. But the symptoms in this case are strange. Or may be not?

Comment: It defaults to an 'auto' layout, http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.4/api/Ext.layout.container.Auto.html. Not strange behavior or anything... you just need to specify a layout if a component will contain other components.